# __int64 for GCC as a Preprocessor Option

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

Usually Microsoft code uses `__int64` which is not understood by GCC. 
I know I can write it as a macro like this:

```
#define __int64 long long
```

But I don't want to do this, due to code portability.
I'm trying to give GCC the following Preprocessor Option:

```
-D__int64="long long"
```

I get the following error due to the space between the two `long`'s:

```
gcc.exe: error: long: No such file or directory
```

How to fix it ?

Comment: instead of long long use int64_t

Comment: error: unknown type name 'int64_t'

Comment: You need `stdint.h` included, as @unwind answered.

Comment: You also need to compile with C99 standard or later. `gcc -std=c99`

Comment: I don't have to modify the code for portability.

Comment: @Lundin I use gcc -std=c99.

Comment: May I ask why you need an 64 bit `int`, I'm just curious why the 32 bit wouldn't be enough?

Comment: @CodeGuru It's the same reason why we use 32-bit while 16-bit (or even 8-bit) are enough. I use 64-bit to hold CAN messages data. But for sure another implementation would have been done using 2 32-bit data holders or even four 8-bit data holders.

Comment: @CodeGuru I don't think a *code guru* will ask a question like that. There are many cases that even 64-bit values are not enough, and that's why there's [`__int128`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html) in gcc and Clang, and also [arbitrary precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic)

Comment: @HeshamEraqi That is not a valid reason, you're performance will go down because of using a larger register than you need. I do use 8 or 16 bit ints if my variable isn't going to need all that space.

@ LưuVĩnhPhúc I think our friend only wanted to know his situation, no need to belittle him.

Comment: `-D__int64="long\ long"` (add more `\\` before the space until it works)

Answer (score 6):

You could use `int64_t`, the standard name for that type, but it will only work if the code does `#include <stdint.h>`, and that's perhaps hoping for too much.

Otherwise you could try to "sneak" in a `typedef` in some common header:

```
typedef long long __int64;
```

Perhaps doing that only if GCC is detected.

Fixing it "your way" should certainly be possible, it looks like some quoting issue.

Comment: Changing the code is not a preferred option in my situation.
I tried different quoting combinations to "my way", and it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you have a double-eval issue if your example doesn't work.  If you can't figure out why that is happening you can try using gcc's `-include` or `-imacros` option.  You would create a new file `gcc_extra_definess` with the `#defines` you want to add, and call `gcc -include gcc_extra_defines ...` to get gcc to read that file and include it before reading the source file.  This is a bit easier than a bunch of `-D` options for defining multiple things, particularly if you have quoting issues or want things other than macros.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a quoting problem caused by gcc seeing only

```
gcc ... -D__int64=long long
```

Can you show us the script or Makefile snippet you use? What shell is it?